# Duplication Function implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I used the above example in typescript it shows 2 errors one with i in the second console.log because of let keyword and the other was test in the first line.The error says Duplication Function implementation. Can anyone have any ideas on it...

```
   function test(){
      for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
         console.log(i);
      }
    console.log("finally:" + i);
    }
    test();
```

Comment: How did you use it and where is it from? Is this all the code?

Comment: yes that is all the I used.Wrote it in typescript file and complied in node

Comment: Your `i` is because when you do `finally`   `i` is then out of scope.  `let` is block level scoped.  The `Duplication Function implementation.` does not make any sense, unless you have defined `test` again somewhere else.

Comment: You should declare the variable i outside the for loop as you are accessing it beyond it's scope. Here is a working code using TypeScript playground - https: // tinyurl . com/yb5fdrgc

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is:

```
  console.log("finally:" + i);
```

That's all.

and how do we fix it?

```
    function test(){
      let i = 0;
      for(; i<5; i++){
         console.log(i);
      }
      console.log("finally:" + i);
    }
    test();
```

Why was it a problem?

Because `let` is a block level scoped.

You shouldn't access it outside the block where you defined it.

Edit: Don't reinitialize the value of `i`.

Comment: No need to initialize i in for, just do for declaration (i; i<5; i++){ ... }

Comment: Yes, you are right. I skipped it. My focus was to declare `i` in the function-block.

Comment: @PrabinPaudel Does JS require the first clause to be non-empty? Why not `for (; i < 5; i++)`?

Comment: @11684 we can skip the first clause if already defined. `for (; i < 5; i++)` this will work perfectly.

Comment: Yeap, that is possible. I think it makes code more readable to have it there!